# Check mouse pointer state using callback

Tags: c#, windows, callback, mouse

I need a reliable method to check the mouse pointer state, and to count how many times it has changed, e.g. from 'normal' pointer to the hourglass/circle or vice versa. It is part of a performance test that measures response times, and the only way to determine whether a certain business process has finished is by observing the mouse pointer, and to count how many times it has gone from "normal" to "busy" and back again. Once it done this twice, the process is finished. I know - it's horrible, and a rubbish workaround, but it's the only thing I can use.
I have implemented something that works, but it has one crucial weakness: if the mouse pointer changes while the thread has gone to sleep, then I "miss" this change and consequently the exit condition. I will reduce the wait time to 5 or 10 milliseconds, but it's still not a good solution.

Here's the code I have, to give you an idea of what's going on:

```
TimeSpan timePassed = new TimeSpan();
bool lastMousePointerState = ConvertMousePointerStateToBoolean(Mouse.CursorName);
bool currentMousePointerState = true;
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

while(pointerChanges <= 1 && timePassed.Seconds < synchDurationTimeout)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    currentMousePointerState = ConvertMousePointerStateToBoolean(Mouse.CursorName);
    var variableComparison = lastMousePointerState ^ currentMousePointerState;
    if (variableComparison.Equals(true))
    {
        pointerChanges++;
    }
    timePassed = stopWatch.Elapsed;
    lastMousePointerState = currentMousePointerState;
}
```

I had a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx) to see if perhaps I could make use of callback functions, and what the article describes *does* work but only for mouse *actions*, not its *state*. Since I have practically no experience with callbacks and making calls out to the OS from .NET, I was hoping someone could tell me if a) what I have in mind is generally possible, and if so b) perhaps provide a working code snippet that would achieve what I need.

Thanks in advance !

Edit: I think the [GetCursorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function might be what I need, but the description is so terse as to be useless to me ;-)

Comment: What an awful workaround! Do you know what cursor only change to hourglasses if it's directly over window which is busy (what if user move mouse away?) and it can be set (in windows) to busy by mouseovering other tasks (and some task may change it to hourglasses for fun, etc) ? Maybe you reconsider continue going this way?

Comment: @Sinatr right you are: it's horrible, but at least (this is the only upside in this scenario) I have complete control over the environment (it's an automated UI test) so I know that there is no human user involved, and I know that the application under test is always in fullscreen mode. At least we can make those assumptions.

Comment: Hi Hiro Protagonist Did you get any other solution ?. I am also trying to find process synchronization for UI Tests but luck!!!!

Comment: Depending on your UI automation tool (Ranorex, QTP, etc.) you may have access to the Windows system. If you do, then the code mentioned in the answer will help you. Generally, you should try to use the tool's built-in features first before going into native C++ kung-fu mode ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the overwhelming number of responses here, I'd like to answer my own question :-)
What I ended up implementing (and what is good enough for my purposes) is to use the [code](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/10/find-active-mouse-cursor-windows/) that was provided by Atomic Object.
I simply generate the dll from the C++ code, and use a loop to check the state. It is still not as good as a callback/notification mechanism, but I need to finish this and this is the best solution to date.